# How to map promise response to object in node typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a response from 3rd party library as

```
{
    "public_id": "123456",
    "Name": "John"
}
```

I need to map to

```
{
    "Id": "123456",
    "FirstName": "John"
}
```

Do I need to have two models which does this? Or do I have an annotation which maps automatically the properties in node typescript? Please Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This won't happen automatically.  If you want to map the keys of an object to a different set of keys, the work will need to be done at runtime in some form.  One way to do this is to make a helper function that maps keys, put it in a library, and use it as needed.

---

Here's one possible implementation, assuming you are using TypeScript 4.1 and have a ES2019+ runtime:

```
const keyMapper =
    <M extends Record<keyof M, K>, K extends PropertyKey>(map: M) =>
        <T extends object>(obj: T): { [K in keyof T as K extends keyof M ? M[K] : K]: T[K] } =>
            Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).
                map(([k, v]) => [k in map ? map[k as keyof M] : k, v])
            ) as any;
```

Before I attempt to explain that, let's see it in action.  We can use `keyMapper()` to make a new function specifically to convert your api response with `public_id` and `Name` keys into your desired value type with `Id` and `FirstName` keys:

```
const mapApiVal = keyMapper({ public_id: "Id", Name: "FirstName" });
```

So `mapApiVal` is a function.  And if we have an api response like this:

```
const apiVal = {
    "public_id": "123456",
    "Name": "John"
}
```

we can convert it into the desired form:

```
const mapped = mapApiVal(apiVal);
/* const mapped: {
    Id: string;
    FirstName: string;
} */
console.log(mapped); // { "Id": "123456", "FirstName": "John" } 
console.log(mapped.Id.repeat(2)); //123456123456
console.log(mapped.FirstName.toUpperCase()); // JOHN
```

So it works, yay!

---

So how does it work?  There are two parts to it: the *typing*, and the *implementation*.  The typing is just the call signature:

```
/* const keyMapper: <M extends Record<keyof M, K>, K extends PropertyKey>(
    map: M) => <T extends object>(obj: T) => 
    { [K in keyof T as K extends keyof M ? M[K] : K]: T[K]; } */
```

It says that `keyMapper` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function that takes a `map` argument of an object type `M` whose keys are anything and whose properties are themselves key-like (`string` or `number` or `symbol`)... and it returns a function.  The function it returns is also generic and takes an `obj` argument of an object type `T`, and returns a value.  The value it returns is a [mapped type with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) (as introduced in TypeScript 4.1).  It says: for each key `K` in the `obj`'s type `T`, we check to see if it is one of the keys of `M`.  If so, we replace `K` with `M[K]` (the value of `M` at key `K`).  If not, we leave `K` alone.  And we leave the property, `T[K]` alone.

Now for the implementation.  It looks like this (with the type info removed):

```
        map => obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).
            map(([k, v]) => [k in map ? map[k] : k, v])
        );
```

Here we are using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert `obj` into an array of key-value pairs, processing these pairs, and then using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to turn that back into an object.  The processing is very similar to the key remapped typing above: for each key `k`, we check to see if it is a key of `map`.  If so, we replace it with `map[k]`, otherwise we leave it as `k`.  And the value `v` is left alone.

The compiler is not sophisticated enough to verify that the implementation satisfies the typings, unfortunately.  To prevent compiler warnings, then, and get the compiler to accept the implementation, I had to use some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): `as keyof M` and `as any`. This means I have taken the responsibility of achieving type safety on myself, for better or worse.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.5#code/LAKFoYwewOwZwC4AIDWBTAngWQIYAc80AnJAXlCUqQB4sk0APBNGAEziQCU1ojXr0GKADMkWADRIA0gD5JU+kxbskABSJRCRBBimYZACgC2+AFxiAlGRkUqd6gBVFzNhygAjAFY8Ehj5-MHC3MAbyQAbQUASxhUTBEkJxwOBUYXFUEEugB+MUiAXSRzKXzAgqQAX2tbO1qkAHkvHwA6YQ0jAFEYBCIotDgDRu8IBGaWHr6B-wtmmrr5kzwDA3CUSQA3fKtSGQiUJBikRaRcxdWkZLihUSxC8zWkTYs5+aQrS5wYDABucDAQAD0ACokNB4MhBLgCMRzLRnMoONxePxMjd5HJpPDXGoNFodHoMIY5otzFhtrtHFiVP4fH4vIFyUg5mFIgdYqjEhcUlSOBycnkSkVpKVEgVvpUkECAX9ILBEEd8ABBPBRABqOAANmQrlCtAYwngAK7uDVRCAAfSirHMACIAJKsG2SAByOCMaFtADEokREK73TbKhZfv8wfL8GrNdqQnMbUaTWbLY7bQBGABMAGYACwAVgAbE7Y-60DbbQApKAACxgNtAFVl4IV0NY2sWysjGoMEfVGuDoGBoLlyEWhGtSBjIDsDvMiF6MAA5iG7N7fQhizOJguQ1UpQ24FANWhmhqoPPjPhR8GkACAeOkPbk-f09n8077yu-W6S+WqzWJXuDyPE8zxHNBWGaB1miINBCBwBADDTCwrxvZ9czzVD8wAw9j1Pc9m2aD81y-ZoECgABVaEiAAYWSNADCQ8UbyQMt6gACWdGUQCAA)